# Select multilayer object from database Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, model, entity-framework-core

I have problem with select data from my DB. Put data to database works fine but get data don't. :(

Model include 10 classes. One class include another class but only one way.
Model:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class A
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public B B { get; set; }
        public C C { get; set; }
        public D D { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
    public class B
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public List<E> ListE { get; set; }
        public List<F> ListF { get; set; }
    }
    public class C
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public G G { get; set; }
        public J J { get; set; }
    }
    public class D
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
    public class E
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public G G { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
    public class F
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public G G { get; set; }
        public H H { get; set; }
        public I I { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
    public class G
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
    public class H
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
    public class I
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
    public class J
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Context for database is basic.
DB context:

```
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options) : base(options) 
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<A>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<B>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<C>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<D>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<E>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<F>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<G>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<H>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<I>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<J>();
        }

        public DbSet<A> Aset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<B> Bset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<C> Cset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<D> Dset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<E> Eset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<F> Fset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<G> Gset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<H> Hset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<I> Iset { get; set; }
        public DbSet<J> Jset { get; set; }
    }
```

Get method:

```
public class DBConnections
    {
        private readonly MyDBContext _context;

        public DBConnections(MyDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<A> GetA()
        {
            return _context.Aset.Select(index => index)
                .Include(i => i.B)
                    .ThenInclude(j => j.ListE
                        .Select(k => k.G))
                .Include(i => i.B)
                    .ThenInclude(j => j.ListF
                    .Select(k => new {
                        k.G,
                        k.H,
                        k.I
                    }))
                .Include(i => i.C)
                    .ThenInclude(i => new {
                        i.G,
                        i.J
                    })
                .Include(i => i.D)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

I'm using simple method for getting data from database and .ThenInclude works fine while I'm trying to load just simple related object or list of object.
The problem happens when I want to load all related object of every object included in mentioned list of objects because the select bellow drops when object refers to null.

```
.Include(i => i.B)
               .ThenInclude(j => j.ListF
                        .Select(k => new {
                            k.G,
                            k.H,
                            k.I
                        }
```

How can I load all related data and related data of child objects in one call to the database?

Comment: Your question is not clear about what you want to ask?

Comment: I edited it for batter understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `new { ... }` nor `Select` are valid `Include` / `ThenInclude` expressions. The include expression should represent a simple property path accessor. Which may require repeating the common paths in order to include additional child properties as explained in [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) - **Including multiple levels**.

In your example, you are supposed to use something like this:

```
.Include(a => a.B)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.ListF)
        .ThenInclude(f => f.G)
.Include(a => a.B)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.ListF)
        .ThenInclude(f => f.H)
.Include(a => a.B)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.ListF)
        .ThenInclude(f => f.I)
```

Since including a simple property also includes all its parent properties, `ThenInclude` for non collection can be skipped and can be used just for including additional data of the elements of a collection navigation property. So the above can be shortened to:

```
.Include(a => a.B.ListF)
    .ThenInclude(f => f.G)
.Include(a => a.B.ListF)
    .ThenInclude(f => f.H)
.Include(a => a.B.ListF)
    .ThenInclude(f => f.I)
```

To better understand it, here is the string `Include` equivalent:

```
.Include("B.ListF.G")
.Include("B.ListF.H")
.Include("B.ListF.I")
```

Comment: I try both your solution, but EF return exception: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IncludeCompiler+IncludeLoadTreeNodeBase+<_AwaitMany>d__8.MoveNext()

Comment: I have one A object in DB with null B, C, D objects. I think the problem will be in this. It is necessary to ossify this condition somehow.

Comment: This is another story. Could be EFC bug, what version are you on?

Comment: Then this is EF Core bug similar or the same as in [Entityframework Core 2.0 error when related object is null in .Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332713/entityframework-core-2-0-error-when-related-object-is-null-in-include). Since the above are the only valid `Include` syntaxes, all you can do is to check their GitHub issue tracker to see when it will be fixed (or suggested workarounds).

Comment: If I'm used `.Include(a => a.B).ThenInclude(b => b.ListF).ThenInclude(f => f.G)` and B is null, EF return exception but B is not null, then this working fine.